# Syntax Error in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I'm just starting to learn Python and I decided to start with 3.2

I'm trying some socket managing code and I get a syntax error. (The line works just fine in 2.7)

Any ideas?

```
        def __init__(self, (socket, address)):
  File "./main.py", line 16
    def __init__(self, (socket, address)):
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a method with a tuple argument in Python 3. This was possible in Python 2 but removed. See [PEP 3113 Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

The syntax made introspection hard, (even impossible for IronPython), was incompatible with other new argument syntax (annotations and keyword-only arguments), produced unhelpful error messages and was one of the least-known and least-used features of the language.

You'll have to do the unpacking in the method:

```
def __init__(self, socket_address):
    socket, address = socket_address
```

Comment: That's interesting - why did they do that?

Comment: @MattDMo: There is other new argument features (keyword-only arguments, annotations) that made this case hard to maintain and it was used *very* rarely.